# Calling a function after map display rather than map load

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, event-listener

I have the following method which I am calling on load of the map. However when I try to turn on a particular layer within this code I am unsuccessful as although the map would have been loaded it would not be displayed. Is there some way to call the method after the map is visible on the display? I also tried including the method in document.ready() however it was also unsuccessful.

```
      app.map.on("load", function () {

                var coords, zoomLevel;
                var urlObject = esri.urlToObject(document.location.href);

                if (urlObject.query && urlObject.query.coords && urlObject.query.zoomLevel && urlObject.query.LotNumber && urlObject.query.LayerName) {
                    var coords = urlObject.query.coords.split(',');

                    var lon = parseFloat(coords[0]);
                    var lat = parseFloat(coords[1]);
                    var lotNumber = urlObject.query.LotNumber;
                    var layerName = urlObject.query.LayerName;

                    var zoomLevel = parseInt(urlObject.query.zoomLevel);
                    var point = new esri.geometry.Point(lon, lat, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 23033 }));

                    for (var i = 0; i < app.map.graphicsLayerIds.length; i++) {
                        var tempLayer = app.map.getLayer(app.map.graphicsLayerIds[i]);

                        var lname = layerName.split(".");
                        layerName = lname[lname.length - 1];

                        if (tempLayer.url.indexOf(layerName) != -1) {
                            tempLayer.show();
                        }
                    }

                    app.map.centerAndZoom(point, zoomLevel);
                }
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map's load event is fired after the first or base layer has been successfully added to the map. You could use the event [update-end](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#event-update-end) since this fires after layers that are updating their content have completed. Since you probably only want to run this when the map first opens, you would use the [on.once](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#once) method to set up the event listener.

Comment: I ended up changing my code around for this however update-end would probably have been a simpler way. Cheers!